# AWK-minimum value finding from text file

Tags: awk

i tried the following code to find minimum value from a text file.but it does not work correctly.It returns empty space as output

```
awk 'NR == 1 {line=$0;min = $3} NR>1 && $3 < min {line = $0;min= $3} END {print line}' snd1
```

My text file snd1.txt contains following values

```
0 1 111
0 2 200
0 3 50
```

But it retuns correct output for the following text file
aaa.txt

```
0 1 141
0 2 223
```

Please help me. i need second column value when third column contains minimum vale.

Comment: I could not reproduce your results when applying your code to file `snd1.txt`. In my case, it successfully prints out the line: `0 3 50`, not empty space. Please check that you're applying your code to the right file.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the variation you're looking for:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || $3 < min { col = $2; min = $3 } END { print col }' snd1.txt
```

Result:

```
3
```